# C++ - Struct needs access to private instance variable of class

Tags: c++, syntax, organization

My C++ is a bit rusty so I was wondering if you could help me out. Basically, I have two structs and a class and the structs need access to the private instance variables of the class.

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    ...
    inline void addEdge(Edge* e);
};

inline void Node::addEdge(Edge* e) {
    char ch = inp[e->startIndex];
    edges[ch] = e;
}

struct Edge {
    Node* next = new Node();
    int startIndex = 0;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Edge e) {
        int index = inp.size() - e.startIndex + endIndex + 1;   // Here the edge needs access to the private members of the Tree class such as string inp, and int endIndex
        // ... do things with index
        return out;
    }
};


class Tree {
public:
    Tree();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Tree s);

private:
    Node* root = nullptr;
    int endIndex = 0;
    std::string inp;
    void foo();
    std::ostream& printTree(std::ostream& out, Node* curr, std::string append="");

};
#endif // TREE_H
```

So obviously the above code doesn't work. I was thinking I would move the structs inside the class. But then the << operator for Edge gives me an "invalid use of non-static data member 'endIndex'" error. One idea I'm sure will work is to pass a reference/pointer to endIndex as a member of Edge when I create the Edge but I was wondering what might be a better way to go about this.

Comment: You seem to know what a `friend` is since you used that declaration for `operator<<`. So just use it for the other case you need it too!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Comment: Note that `friend` isn't the best solution, and wont even help you get all the way. First of all the `Node` and `Edge` classes needs to know about the `Tree` class, which means you need to reorder declarations and function definitions. Then the `Node` and `Edge` classes also need to know about the specific `Tree` instance they are a part of. This will create a pretty badly designed web of dependencies and links, something that will be hard to understand and maintain. You might want to rethink your design, and see if you can't come up with a better way of handling whatever you need to do.

Comment: Your comment is exactly my concern. The friend solution relies on them knowing the instance of the tree they belong to. The thing is, I actually need the structs to have more than just access to endIndex. If endIndex of the Tree changes, all the edges need to use this new endIndex without me having to update them (an O(1) operation). Do you think passing a pointer to endIndex when creating the Edges would be a good fix?

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use the visitor pattern.

Here's a brief, incomplete example, to give you the idea:

```
class Tree
{
    Node _Node;
    std::list<Node> _Children;
public:
    ... // other stuff, like AddChild(), etc.

    void Traverse(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.HandleNodeData(_Node.Data);
        traverseChildren(visitor);
    }
};
```

I would also consider to implement the Tree class as a template.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood me; I'm not writing a Tree class per se (I just simplified my code to what it is so it wouldn't be overwhelmingly long to post here). I'm actually writing a complicated data structure that has harsh complexity requirements and thus I need the edges to reference endIndex in an O(1) manner.

Comment: What do you mean with "I need the edges to reference endIndex in an O(1) manner"? <br/>  I think Visitor pattern is still an option, because you get the possibility to pass private Data to the visitor.

Comment: I'll definitely read up on the visitor pattern.

What I meant by referencing in an O(1) manner is this. The edges are keeping track of substrings of the main input string by using the index positions of the substring. As endIndex changes, the substring that each edge stores effectively changes because the indexes change. But this is done in O(1) since you never actually have to manually change the substring value stored by each of the edges.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone's future reference, I went with the pointer solution for now; seems to get the job done. My only doubt about this is whether endIndex in the Tree class needs to necessarily be on the stack (I think it does). Can anyone clarify?

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    ...
    inline void addEdge(Edge* e);
};

inline void Node::addEdge(Edge* e) {
    char ch = inp[e->startIndex];
    edges[ch] = e;
}

struct Edge {
    Edge(int start, int* endIndex) {        
        this->startIndex = start;
        this->endIndex = endIndex;
    }
    Node* next = new Node();
    int startIndex = 0;
    int* endIndex;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Edge e) {
        std::string value = inp.substr(e.startIndex,  *e.endIndex - e.startIndex + 1);
        out << "(---- " << value << "[" << e.startIndex << ", " << *e.endIndex << "] ---->)";
        return out;
    }
};


class Tree {
public:
    Tree();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Tree s);

private:
    Node* root = nullptr;
    int* endIndex = new int;   // am i correct in saying this needs to be on the stack? 
    std::string inp;
    void foo();
    std::ostream& printTree(std::ostream& out, Node* curr, std::string append="");

};
#endif // TREE_H
```